# Let two matrices $A_{nx}, B_{nxn}$. T/F: if there exists invertible $P_{nxn}$ s.t $P$ diagonizes $A$ and also $B$, then $P$ also diagonizes $A+B$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let two matrices $A_{nx}, B_{nxn}$. T/F: if there exists invertible $P_{nxn}$ s.t  $P$ diagonizes $A$ and also $B$, then $P$ also diagonizes $A+B$.

I don't know how to approach this question. I don't see why this is true, but I also don't know how to quickly check if a given marix is diagonalizible or not

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What does it mean for $P$ to diagonalize $A$? Note that
$$
P(A+B)P^{-1}
= PAP^{-1}+ PBP^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Existence of $P$ translates to the fact that $A$ and $B$ both have diagonal representations in a certain basis of $R^n$. Each $v$ from this basis is an eigenvector for $A$ and $B$ with generally differing eigenvalues. But

$$ Av=\lambda_1v, \ Bv=\lambda_2v \implies (A+B)v=(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)v$$
Thus $A+B$ also is diagonalized by same basis, i.e. by same $P$.

Comment: I learned Linear Algebra through vector spaces and basis. So, I tend to always treat matrices as linear maps between finite dimensional vector spaces.

It has its pros and cons.